# How to screenshot the screen without the dialog itself in MFC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, atl

Currently I have done a MFC dialog application. There is just one dialog window and a button. When I press the button, it takes a screenshot and save it to HBITMAP. That works fine already.

However, I am wondering, can I take a screenshot of the screen without my window? Basically, What I want is: When I take the screenshot, my dialog window is still running on top, but it will not appear on the image that I saved. The image will look like as if my dialog window is not there.

I guess I need to use some device context to capture the image behind my dialog window and combine it with the original one. But I have really no idea how to do it.

Anyone care to enlighten me how to do this? Which are the concepts I should use?

Comment: The image behind your dialog may not exist - most windows paint themselves on demand, only when exposed. You would likely have to hide your dialog (`ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)`), wait a little to give time for newly exposed windows to repaint, then take the screenshot and show the dialog again.

Comment: There is certainly a message you can catch on completed SW_HIDE that can trigger the screenshot too.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: the problem is not in knowing when your window is done hiding - that's when `ShowWindow` returns. The problem is in knowing when the window underneath gets around to processing its `WM_PAINT` message. For all you know, its thread is sitting in a busy loop, or something. That's where a race is - between somebody else's thread putting pixels onto the screen, and your thread grabbing them. You can't reliably know what that other thread is doing.

Comment: I think you need to change the interface of your program. Why do you need the window? What is it used for. Have a look at the program called [Snippy][1]. It resides in the system tray and has a global shortcut, or the system tray menu option. Do the same for yours. [1]:http://en.kioskea.net/download/download-145-snippy

Comment: Can you see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44162727/383779 ?